# Not saving data after upgrading from 7.26 to 7.35

Tags: 7

I recently update my Drupal site and is working fine on my local machine ie: localhost.
After uploading the site to the hosting it is not saving the form/data.
I'm not even able login to system on first attempt, it is not showing any error as well.

1 - I make sure that .htaccess files is moved to the server.

2 - I clear Drupal and browser cache several times.

3 - No javascript/jquery error on console.

4 - Check on different browsers.

I'm lost what else can be doing problem, Please guide me to the right path.

PHP info = http://worldstogethertravel.com/info.php

TIA :)

Comment: can you disable all contrib module and check for the same..some times this might be because of some updated contributed module

Comment: Check your database user has sufficient rights, check the permission on the `mysite/files` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Apply the patch from here:
   https://www.drupal.org/node/1313912

   cd sites/all/modules/contrib/taxonomy_access

   wget https://www.drupal.org/files/1313912-5.patch

   cat 1313912-5.patch | patch -p1
2. go here and rebuild permissions.
   /admin/reports/status/rebuild
3. Clear the cache